# Characteristic classess of Cliford bundle of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, characteristic-classes, clifford-algebras

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.
Let $E$ be the Cliford bundle associated to  $TM$.
Does the structure of $E$, as a vector bundle depend on choosing the Riemannian metric $g$? How can we write the characteristic classes of $E$ in term of    characteristic classes of $M$ and some invariants of the metric?

Comment: The bundle of Clifford algebras is isomorphic as a vector bundle to the bundle of exterior forms $\Lambda^*T^*M$. Check your favourite textbook on the subject. From the special lambda ring structure of topological $K$ theory we know that characteristic classes of $E$ can be computed from those of $TM$. Note that all this holds even if you pass to Lorentzian metrics or any other signature.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  Thank you for your answer.